# Find unique elements in a matrix other than 0

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of the following form

```
b < -matrix(c(1, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000,
              0, 0.1266234, 0.1590909, 0.7142857,
              0, 0.1266234, 0.1590909, 0.7142857,
              0, 0.1266234, 0.1590909, 0.7142857),
            nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

I want to get all the unique element in each column of `b` other than 0. And it should be returned as a vector of the following form:-

```
qq <- c(1, 0.1266234, 0.1590909, 0.7142857)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select items that are non-zero and find unique ones:

```
qq <- unique(b[b != 0])
qq

[1] 1.0000000 0.1266234 0.1590909 0.7142857
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqueValues <- apply(b, 2, function(x) setdiff(unique(x), 0))
```

Keep in mind, that calculating unique values on numeric vectors has a bias due to accuracy. E.g. 0.99999 and 0.99998 are treated as different elements.